# facebook PHP SDK SSL error - why?

Tags: php, facebook

We're trying to login with facebook connect.
it works on localhost but fails on the server on this line:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

there facebook exception:

```
object(FacebookApiException)#2 (8) {
["result":protected]=>
array(2) {
["error_code"]=>
int(60)
["error"]=>
array(2) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(146) "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
 error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"
   ["type"]=>
   string(13) "CurlException"
  }
 }
["message":protected]=>
string(146) "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
 error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"
["string":"Exception":private]=>
string(0) ""
["code":protected]=>
int(60)
["file":protected]=>
string(43) "C:\xampp\htdocs\taska\api\base_facebook.php"
["line":protected]=>
int(967)
["trace":"Exception":private]=>
array(5) {
[0]=>
array(6) {
  ["file"]=>
  string(43) "C:\xampp\htdocs\taska\api\base_facebook.php"
  ["line"]=>
  int(899)
  ["function"]=>
  string(11) "makeRequest"
  ["class"]=>
  string(12) "BaseFacebook"
  ["type"]=>
  string(2) "->"
  ["args"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(29) "https://graph.facebook.com/me"
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["method"]=>
      string(3) "GET"
      ["access_token"]=>
      string(48) "2750040a2d1e2"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you have enabled the `ssl_module` in Apache

you can do this by

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Your fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt may need to be updated. You can find the latest version on the [Facebook PHP SDK github page](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt).

[This bug report on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/412291762177195/) states:

> fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt provided by the sdk is issued by DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
>   But graph.facebook.com/ is using cert from www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.by Ref. LIABILITY LTD.(c)97 VeriSign

Not sure how helpful this answer is 2 months after the fact, but updating this file worked for me.